# Symbol in string changed in iOS circa 13.3 / XCode 11 / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, symbols

I am using a checkbox symbol in a UITableViewCell derived class.  The init method of the class is shown.  When I upgraded from iOS 12.0 to iOS 13.3, the checkbox symbol has changed as the images below show (left = iOS 12.0, right = iOS 13.3).  Not only did the symbol change its look, it also changed its size.  You can see my work-around for that in the code below.

I removed scene support in my iOS 13.3 app if that has any bearing on the problem.

Can someone help me understand what changed between versions?  Do you have a recommendation as to how to avoid having a change like this in the future while still using a symbol?

[image: iOS 12.0]
[image: iOS 13.3]

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {

    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    checkboxButton = UIButton(type: .custom)

    // TODO: When drop support for pre iOS 13, #available can be removed as well as the 'else'
    var uncheckedSize: CGFloat
    var checkedSize: CGFloat
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        uncheckedSize = 32
        checkedSize = 25
    } else {
        uncheckedSize = 20
        checkedSize = 24
    }
    let unchecked = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "☐", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: uncheckedSize)]);
    let checked = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "☑︎", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: checkedSize)]);
    checkboxButton.setAttributedTitle(unchecked, for: .normal)
    checkboxButton.setAttributedTitle(checked, for: .selected)

    checkboxButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    checkboxButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(44), height: CGFloat(44))

    contentView.addSubview(checkboxButton)

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let guide = contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide // since iOS 11.0
        NSLayoutConstraint.useAndActivate([
            checkboxButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor),
            checkboxButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            checkboxButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(44)),
            checkboxButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(44))
            ])
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.useAndActivate([
            checkboxButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            checkboxButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            checkboxButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(44)),
            checkboxButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(44))
            ])
    }
}
```

Comment: I imagine Apple tweaked the system font that you're using. Or does your 13.3 device have Bold Font enabled in Settings? Are you somehow overriding the system font on 13.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS `System Font` changed between 12 and 13.

To avoid this type of issue in the future:

- use a specific font instead of the system font
- use a bitmap graphic (png)
- use a custom view and draw it exactly how you want it to look